# RichTextBlockOverflow content

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, richtextblock, richtextblockoverflow

How can I get content from RichTextBlockOverflow (for example some text)?
And maybe someone know can I set RichTextBlockOverflow invisible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RichTextBlockOverflow` doesn't have its own content, it shows overflow content from the `RichTextBlock` it is linked to. If you want to know what text shows in the `RichTextBlockOverflow` you can use [`ContentStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblockoverflow.contentstart) [`ContentEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblockoverflow.contentend) properties and extract text from the `RichTextBlock` using [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock.select.aspx) and [`SelectedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock.selectedtext.aspx)